# Is there any workaround / solution in Eslint for TypeScript to get spaces in generic classes/methods

Tags: typescript, generics, types, eslint

I am trying to get Typescript ESLint to detect when there is no space between the angle brackets when you want to set a type to a generic method/class. The main goal is to get warnings / errors if the spaces are missing. Automatic fixing is just a nice to have.

For example this is the incorrect code:

```js
class MyGenricClass<T> {
   MyGenericProperty: T;
   MyHttpResponse: <HttpResponse<T>>;
}

const InstancedClass = new MyGenricClass<string>();
```

I want the the generic types to have spaces inside the angle brackets like the following:

```
class MyGenricClass< T > {
   MyGenericProperty: T;
   MyHttpResponse: < HttpResponse< T > >;
}

const InstancedClass = new MyGenricClass< string >();
```

I've checked the following which I could find in TypeScript-Eslint documentation:

- **@typescript-eslint/func-call-spacing** - just adds white space before the function call
- **@typescript-eslint/type-annotation-spacing** - Works for `let foo: string = "bar";` but not for the angle brackets
- **@typescript-eslint/space-before-function-paren** - Feels the same as func-call-spacing

I've also tried to google and duckduckgo, without any success. Searched that I've done are:

- typescript eslint space between generic
- typescript eslint generic spacing
- typescript eslint template spacing
- typescript eslint generic type spacing
- typescript eslint type annotation spacing

To be honest, I am not sure what's the correct naming for what I want to achieve. So I would appreciate some suggestions where I could look for a solution or a possible workaround. Worst case scenario is to write this rule myself, and create a PR to @typescript-eslint.

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5):

Oh, boy.
This was rough.

First, I didn't know what they were called either. They're [generics](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html)
So, I did some googling myself. Ran into the same issue.
[The documentation of `keyword-spacing` in @typescript-eslint](https://github.com/typescript-eslint/typescript-eslint/blob/eaaa2047ca54f098dcdd32aaf5d8949495c6be26/packages/eslint-plugin/docs/rules/keyword-spacing.md) states that "This version adds support for generic type parameters on function calls.".
But like, how?So I dig through the source code, because go figure. No dice.

Then, I check issues.
[That's where I found this](https://github.com/typescript-eslint/typescript-eslint/issues/4433).

*Damnit.*

---

So the search continues. Digging through some pulls comes up with [func-call-spacing](https://github.com/typescript-eslint/typescript-eslint/pull/448), claiming the same thing as the last one when it comes to generics.

Let's just say that it didn't pan out, either.

---

So, my conclusion is that it isn't going to be implemented in the main @typescript-eslint, but you could probably write an extension